# why tree-based model do not need one-hot encoding for nominal data?

Tags: machine-learning, model, random-forest, one-hot-encoding, boosting

We usually do one-hot encoding for nominal data to make it more reasonable to count the *distance* among features or the *weight*, but I often heard that tree-based model like random forest or boosting model do not need do one-hot encoding but I have searched the Internet and have no idea, can anyone told me why or guide me some materials to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I often heard that tree-based model like random forest or boosting
>   model do not need do one-hot encoding

This is not necessarily true, as some implementations will apply different logic to numerical and categorical variables, so it is best to to encode categorical variables appropriately for the library you are using.

However, it *sometimes* might be OK to use numerical encoding for decision tree models, because they are just looking for places to split the data, they are not multiplying inputs by weights, for example. Contrast this with a neural network that would interpret `red=1, blue=2` as meaning that blue is *twice* red, which is obviously not what you want.

Comment: thanks,your example gave me some intuition,since the decision tree just split the samples by check the certain input value equals with chosen feature value or not and does not use the value to count something like weight or distance